# REGEX - Preciso dar replace em um ; (ponto e vírgula) que está entre aspas em uma string

Tags: php, string, regex

Tenho uma string com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
2052682;"27/09/2013 16:05:59.000000";"2013";"09";"Processo Encaminhado para Cobrança";"Reclamação";"Telefone";"NÃO";"Telefone";"HEMOGRAMA COMPLETO [INCLUI: CONTAGEM GLOBAL DE LEUCÓCITOS; CONTAGEM GLOBAL DE ERITRÓCITOS]";;;;;"Reclamação";;2052682;"27/09/2013 16:22:00.000000";"NÚCLEO";;;"Em Cobrança";"SIM";"31/08/2015 00:00:00.000000"
```

É um .CSV separado por ponto e vírgula, só dentro do dado também tem o `;` impossibilitando a quebra da informação corretamente.

Precisaria dar um replace nesse dado antes de dar explode.

Já tentei usar um `$pattern = '"[;]"'` - mas ele substitui todos os `;`.

Precisaria ser só os pontos e vírgulas que estão entre aspas.

Comment: Não use regex, use funções próprias para ler CSV (conforme indicou a resposta abaixo). Remover as aspas pode dar problema nos casos em que o conteúdo contém `;`, por exemplo: `"abc;def";123`, o texto "abc;def" é um único campo, mas se vc remover as aspas serão lidos como 2 campos separados ("abc" e "def"). Esqueça regex, use a ferramenta correta para o problema: se tem um CSV, use funções que sabem lidar com esse formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para a estrutura de dados apresentados na pergunta não tem o porque de forçar a substituição do ponto e virgula dentro de um campo string.
A função [`str_getcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-getcsv.php) no seu terceiro parâmetro `string $enclosure` define o caractere que delimitará strings cujo o conteúdo não será analisado como CSV, no seu caso sendo suficiente apenas fazer a leitura com `str_getcsv($csv, ";", '"')`:

```php
<?php

$csv = <<<CSV
2052682;"27/09/2013 16:05:59.000000";"2013";"09";"Processo Encaminhado para Cobrança";"Reclamação";"Telefone";"NÃO";"Telefone";"HEMOGRAMA COMPLETO [INCLUI: CONTAGEM GLOBAL DE LEUCÓCITOS; CONTAGEM GLOBAL DE ERITRÓCITOS]";;;;;"Reclamação";;2052682;"27/09/2013 16:22:00.000000";"NÚCLEO";;;"Em Cobrança";"SIM";"31/08/2015 00:00:00.000000"
CSV;

print_r(str_getcsv($csv, ";", '"'));
```

resultando:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2052682
    [1] => 27/09/2013 16:05:59.000000
    [2] => 2013
    [3] => 09
    [4] => Processo Encaminhado para Cobrança
    [5] => Reclamação
    [6] => Telefone
    [7] => NÃO
    [8] => Telefone
    [9] => HEMOGRAMA COMPLETO [INCLUI: CONTAGEM GLOBAL DE LEUCÓCITOS; CONTAGEM GLOBAL DE ERITRÓCITOS]
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [12] => 
    [13] => 
    [14] => Reclamação
    [15] => 
    [16] => 2052682
    [17] => 27/09/2013 16:22:00.000000
    [18] => NÚCLEO
    [19] => 
    [20] => 
    [21] => Em Cobrança
    [22] => SIM
    [23] => 31/08/2015 00:00:00.000000
)
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/CSVstrgetcsv#main.php)</sup>

Comment: Show! Valeu pela dica!